# Is there a way to Capture http/s response from external server

Tags: javascript, http

Is there a way to capture response sent from external server using javascript in our webpage. For example i have a iframe with youtube video object in my page. I need to capture response sent (Video details) by youtube whenever the video is played.

Comment: Spy on `XMLHttpRequest`. So all the requests will go through the fake XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

You'd need to access the `window` object of the `iframe`, which you can't because of the same origin policy. If it were the same origin, you could possibly build in  `XmlHttpRequest`'s prototype to capture the data. You may be able to proxy the request from Youtube to your servers, so it would have the same origin.